# Unable to upload images to Google Cloud Platform through my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-cloud-platform

So I created an app on my local machine that allows me to upload images to Google Cloud Platform. When I use the app on my local machine, I'm able to upload to the cloud. However, when I uploaded it to Heroku, I get a “We’re sorry, but something went wrong” when I try to upload images. When I ran the logs, I got "ActionView::Template::Error (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.):" How do I fix this? 
I'm working on a portfolio and want to show off what I can do. Here's my github repository: https://github.com/isepulveda78/yelpdemo

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: I changed that. I actually had that in the beginning, but I changed it back to local since it wasn't working on Heroku but on my local machine. I got it to work after I uninstalled a couple of gems. According to a post on STF, the fog-google gem is out-of-date. When I took that off and used active storage, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 42 in **config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

with

```
config.active_storage.service = :google
```

For more information : [Setup Active Storage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup)

**EDIT :**

After watching your github your images do not go into google cloud even local.
You have checked in your google console if you find your images ?

Follow these different tutorials for the use of active storage and google cloud.

[Active_storage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-files-to-records)

[Google Cloud Storage account](https://medium.com/@pjbelo/setting-up-rails-5-2-active-storage-using-google-cloud-storage-and-heroku-23df91e830f8#5084)

Comment: I will try that first thing tomorrow. They do upload in my local environment but not on Heroku.